# How to get and compare the image resources of two images in android dynamically?

Tags: android

I need to compare the image resources of two ImageViews and display whether they match or not.
I have tried solutions to the similar questions asked in stackoverflow but they are resulting in the crash of my app.
just mentioning I have used setImageResource to set the image so please post the solution which don't require me to remove setImageResource method

Answer (score 0):

you can compare imageViews in kotlin like this:

```
if(imageView1.drawable.constantState == imageView2.drawable.constantState){
//Do something
}
```

or if you like in java:

```
if(imageView1.getDrawable().getConstantState() == imageView2.getDrawable().getConstantState()){
//Do something
}
```